# python not rendering context in data view

Tags: python, django

I have created a custom report in python (using logic I have used in another app that I know works). However, in this particular app it doesn't appear to be rendering the context that I referring to with the render in my view. I can see that it is printing out the query in the python parser but the issue is that it is not rendering in the template.

Models.py

```
class NegativeBehaviour(models.Model):
    behaviour = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, unique=True, null=True, choices=NegativeBehaviourType)
    behaviourdesc = models.TextField(max_length=2500)
    subjects = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=Subjects, default=None)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=Modules, default=None)
    students = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name = "Negative_Behaviour_Students", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name = "Negative_Behaviour_Teachers", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    C1 = BehaviourManagerC1()
    C2 = BehaviourManagerC2()
    C3 = BehaviourManagerC3()
    C4 = BehaviourManagerC4()
    C5 = BehaviourManagerC5()
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Behaviour",
        verbose_name_plural = "Behaviours"
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.behaviour
        return str(self.user.id)
    
class PositiveBehaviour(models.Model):
    behaviour = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, unique=True, null=True, choices=PositiveBehaviourType)
    behaviourdesc = models.TextField(max_length=2500)
    subjects = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=Subjects, default=None)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=Modules, default=None)
    students = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name = "Positive_Behaviour_Students", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name = "Positive_Behaviour_Teachers", on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    A1 = BehaviourManagerA1()
    A2 = BehaviourManagerA2()
    A3 = BehaviourManagerA3()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Behaviour",
        verbose_name_plural = "Behaviours"
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.behaviour
        return str(self.user.id)
```

behaviouralData.py

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as sa
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import *
from reportlab.lib.styles import *
from reportlab.lib import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import requests


class Behaviour():

    def __init__(self, result1=None, result2=None, body=None, Core=None, CoreQA=None, Specialist=None, SpecialistQA=None, DesignandMake=None, DesignandMakeQA=None, Nonexamassessment=None, NonexamassessmentQA=None):
        self.title = title
        self.subtitles = subtitles
        self.body = body
        self.Core = Core
        self.CoreQA = CoreQA
        self.Specialist = Specialist
        self.SpecialistQA = SpecialistQA
        self.DesignandMake = DesignandMake
        self.DesignandMakeQA = DesignandMakeQA
        self.Nonexamassessment = Nonexamassessment
        self.NonexamassessmentQA = NonexamassessmentQA
        
class Negative(Behaviour):
        
    def GradeOutputs(self, User):
        cnxn_str = ("Driver={SQL Server};"
                "Server=127.0.0.1;"
                "Database=Healthcare;"
                "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        Core = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.behaviour_negativebehaviour WHERE students_id = '%s'" %User)
        Result1 = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in Result1:
            print(row[0])
            print("\n")
        cnxn.commit()
        cnxn.close
        return Result1
        
class Positive(Behaviour):

    def GradeOutputs(self, User):
        cnxn_str = ("Driver={SQL Server};"
                "Server=127.0.0.1;"
                "Database=Healthcare;"
                "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        Shakespheare = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.behaviour_positivebehaviour WHERE students_id = '%s'" %User)
        Result2 = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in Result2:
            print(row[0])
            print("\n")
        cnxn.commit()
        cnxn.close
        return Result2
```

views.py

```
def Reports(request):
    User=request.user.id
    if request.method == 'GET':
        sampleset = a()
        one = sampleset.GradeOutputs(User)
        sampleset = b()
        two = sampleset.GradeOutputs(User)
        print(one, two)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        sampleset = a()
        one = sampleset.GradeOutputs(User)
        sampleset = b()
        two = sampleset.GradeOutputs(User)  
        print(one, two)
    return render(request, 'Behaviour/Report.html', context = {"one":one, "two":two})
```

Behaviour/Report.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href =".\grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Subjects</title>
</head>

<body>
{% block content %}
<div class = "div-1">
    <h1>Welcome to Inspired Intelligence - Education</h1>
    <a href={% url 'Education:School:Grades:Home' %}>Grade Home</a>
    <br>
    <h2>Behaviour Report</h2>
    <h3>Negative Behaviour:</h3>
    <h2>{{one.as_p}}</h2>
    <br>
    <h3>Positive Behaviour</h3>
    <h2>{{two.as_p}}</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Python as a language does not render reports in templates. Which framework or library are you using for this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Seems to be django, based on the imports. I added the tag for it.

Comment: If it is possible to store text against a variable, then it must be possible to execute a sql query as text then call the function as part of the view and render the output to a template. I can do this using plain text, so should be able to achieve the same result with sql?